# How to check what the last dynamically added element was and run a Particular Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a code for a chat application. What I want is, When someone types something and clicks on send, I want to add a 'row' (dynamically) inside a container called 'chat'. The 'row' contains the message in another container called 'message' (which is also created dynamically). I was able to do that. But what I want to do is this, when someone types two message in a row (i mean before getting any reply from the person he/she is chatting with) and hits send I don't want add an entire 'row' in the 'chat'. I just want to append the 'message' inside the row, something like :

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   if(last added element was .row.user) {
     $('.row').appnd('<div class="message">/div>');
   } else {

   }
});
```

Is there anyway to achieve what I described is pseudo code?

here is the HTML

```
<div class="chat">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="message"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fairly trivial using `.last().hasClass()` or `.last().is()`

Comment: Does not work when content was added dynamically. Can you share a working snippet?

Comment: Will work fine if elements are there, regardless of how they got there. Are you using proper arguments? Easy to look both those methods up in jQuery API

Comment: Yes I did. But that way it adds the code to the body not inside the .chat element

Comment: No idea what code you are using..and not clear where you are adding classes either. Something wrong with your code if you are adding to body. Create a small demo in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```
function addMessage(message, user) {
    chat = $("#chat"); //Get a reference to the chat div.
    lastRow = chat.find(".row:last"); //Get a reference to the last row of the chat.
    if(lastRow.attr("data-user") == user) {
        //Its the same user who posted last time.
        lastRow.append("<div class='message'>" + message + "</div>");
    }
    else {
        //It's a different user.
        chat.append('<div class="row" data-user="' + user + '"><div class="message">' + message + '</div></div>');
    }
}
```

[Working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hyLc8kq0/)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .row{
            border: 1px solid;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chat"></div>
        Message: <input type="text" id="message"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <button onclick="sendMessage('userA');">Send Message as User A</button>
        <button onclick="sendMessage('userB');">Send Message as User B</button>
        <script>
            var lastUser = null;
            function sendMessage(user){
                var chat = document.querySelector('.chat');
                var message = document.getElementById('message');
                if(user != lastUser){
                    var newRow = document.createElement('div');
                    newRow.className = 'row';
                    var newMessage = document.createElement('div');
                    newMessage.className = 'message';
                    newMessage.innerHTML = '<strong>' + user + '</strong><br/>';
                    newMessage.innerHTML += message.value;
                    newRow.appendChild(newMessage);
                    chat.appendChild(newRow);
                    lastUser = user;
                }else{
                    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.chat .row');
                    var lastRow = rows[rows.length - 1];
                    var lastMessage = lastRow.querySelector('.message');
                    lastMessage.innerHTML += '<br/>' + message.value;
                }
                message.value = '';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```